# Can I make FireFox settings from an old PC into a new profile on a new PC?

Tags: firefox

I have two PCs (actually, once PC and the harddrive from a dead one).

I never used FireFox profiles, unless there is a default profile, that is.

So, I would like to be able to take the od FF settings from the harddrive and use them in FF on my new PC - but separately, not erged, so that I can switch between the two lots of settings (bookmarks, passwords, form filling details, etc)

Can I do that? If so, how?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/).

> FEBE backs up your extensions, themes, bookmarks, preferences,
>   passwords, cookies and just about everything else Firefox offers (it
>   can even backup/restore your entire profile). You can selectively
>   restore only the items you need. For instance, you may just want your
>   bookmarks restored and leave everything else as it was.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Bibhas. I will just check if it can still treat the old one as separate "profile", rather than merging them into my "new" profile, but in some way I can probably work something out ..